# Aspiring Engineer Math Book

Tags: self-learning, education

I am in search of a math book that will teach me all that i need to have a basic and concrete foundation in engineering math so that i may move forward into more advanced engineering math books and/or so i may understand mathematical concepts in electrical math/physics books with great confidence (As the prerequisites to those books will have been covered). I have found a Basic Engineering math book that teaches from the very basics to integrals and differentiation, all of which i have already self learned but want to make sure i miss no steps and can assure myself that i know what i need to move into more advanced studies. A book that will teach me, and prime me for electrical engineering math (And covers the Algebra/Geometry/Trigonometry/Basic Calc). I'm getting redundant and hope you understand my question. I am not trying to cut corners, but have purchased many books to read, and feel as if i am covering concepts that are not necessary (going cover to cover spending months to years), so i want the bare bones but everything i need so i may move into more engineering-advanced topics. Thank you very much for reading. I am not in college, but plan to be.

Answer (score 0):

> [Elementary Calculus : An Infinitesimal Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486484521)

This is nice book, I love the easy language used in this book.
Also there are more than enough examples on each topic.

The practice questions range from very easy to moderately hard.

Only down side is that only answers to odd problems are given.

Comment: I have "Calculus: an Intuitive and Physical Approach" by Morris Kline which seems to cover the same thing

Comment: @DoublePole  Since you want to do EE then you should get a complex analysis book.